# trigger event when a pod is created or deleted in kubernetes to write or delete its IP in some database

Tags: docker, events, kubernetes, triggers, kubernetes-pod

We have a system of two application A & B deployed over kubernetes cluster. What we need is to set an event/trigger in kubernetes. So each time a pod of application B is created, it will trigger an action to add its IP to configmap. Also when any pod of application B is deleted, it will trigger an action to remove its IP from the configmap.

Is there any built in object in kubernetes to perform such function, or do we need a 3rd party plugin?

Comment: This sounds like you're describing a Service, which can publish a DNS record for all pods matching some set of labels.  If it's not, then you need a custom controller.

Answer (score 4):

Basically you have two options:

- Use the kubernetes (watch) API and handle the pod created/deleted events accordingly
- Use container lifecycle hooks to react to container creation/deletion, https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/

The later is at the container level, but should work for your use case as well.